# What to do when someone always rejects your suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, review-abuse

Today, I noticed that two of my suggested edits was rejected by the same person, So I said that maybe I didn't edited much things or I was little superfluous in that two questions and maybe he/she is right (at this time, both edits are not yet approved or rejected as they need two other rejections or three approved as you know).

The probelm is that I took a look in the history of my suggested edits, and I discovered that this user is **always** rejecting **all** my suggested edits! and in many timeshe is the only person rejecting my edits! within 68 approved edits he/she rejected, at least 8 suggested edits (I didn't finished the count as I can't check all the 68 one).

Is that a normal behavior for a user with more than **9k rep**? If not, what should I do?

Comment: I'd probably consider myself lucky if I were you. I looked over some of your rejects - I would have rejected them for sure. I'd also reject some of the ones you earned rep on. IMHO, there's *far* too many edits being approved with no thought. Getting rep for making bad edits shouldn't be your goal.

Comment: Thanks for yout reply, I will absolutely chanhe my edits behavior based on the answer above. But believe me, its not about rep, I m working all the day and I dont do that only for rep, I tried to help but apparently i did it on a wrong way. Anyway, thanks for your answers

Comment: 67 edits is only 134 rep, so it's really not about rep :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137755/217863

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that the way it sounds. I should have said the "proverbial 'your'". Getting more rep brings more privs. The missed rep may not matter to you for stature, but if you think those edits should've been approved you're confused based on feedback from higher rep users; it's a circular relationship. I should have said - earning rep by doing the best edit possible *should* be your goal.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils no worries :) and Thanks for your advices, they are really welcome

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm noticing that a lot of your suggested edits are merely putting things into inline code blocks, and a lot of them *don't need to be* in inline code blocks. I'm actually surprised that more of them aren't being rejected. Inline code has a bit of subjectiveness to it, in that some users find its over-use to be detrimental to the post rather than helpful. For example, I find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7103814) rather unnecessary. None of that is code. I believe you were looking for the italics button, which is more often used for mathematical expressions.

It's unlikely any user is targeting you. It's much more likely that they've been rejecting your edits because they believe your use of inline code blocks didn't benefit the post at hand. Since all of your edits keep following the same pattern (for the most part), their opinion can look troublesome even when it's not.

As an aside: I would've explicitly rejected [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7122029) because that is a blatant misuse of inline code formatting.

I'm pretty sure I've posted this before, but I don't remember where, so here is a re-cap summary:

Inline code should only ever be used for something that would *actually appear in code*. Further, over-use of inline code blocks can make a post harder to read, so you should use it sparingly for longer pieces of code. One-word class and variable names can easily be read as part of a sentence and generally do not need to be formatted as code because they just make the post look weird and (again) harder to read.

Comment: Thanks animuson for your detailed and well explained answer, as explained above qi didn't mean to get just rep, i was trying to help but unfortunately i did it it the wrong way, I will absolutely improve the quality of my edits and avoid the inline formatting.  Thanks for your guidance :)

Comment: Hm -- IMO console error output *may* be tagged as code. Then again, Tarik missed both the leading "Hi" and trailing "Thanks" -- perhaps that triggered the "not good *enough*" rejects.